# How to improve the quality of AMR audio recordings in Windows?

Tags: windows, audio-recording, amr

How to improve the quality of AMR audio recordings in Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you recording? I guess you are talking about the material you were referring to in your previous questions. If so, then you can't really improve the quality.

To be more general: **You can't improve the objective quality of a recording after it is done.**

You could improve:

- The microphone used for recording
- The signal chain altogether (cables, shielding)
- The analogue to digital converters
- The file format (i.e. using uncompressed WAV instead of AMR or MP3 files)

If you have a small voice recorder, as I would guess from your questions, you obviously can't change anything of this except for using a directional external microphone which would help make voices stand out from ambient noise.

> A super-cardioid microphone is similar to a hyper-cardioid, except there is more front pickup and less rear pickup. These three patterns are commonly used as vocal or speech microphones, since they are good at rejecting sounds from other directions.

In my previous answers however I mentioned **equalizing** as a proper technique to filter noise out and improve voice recognition. This might help you **subjectively improve the quality**.

Comment: This file is a different one and it has some recordings which is recorded using AMR format I tried increasing the kbps(knowing it might not help) and it didnt. And I need to understand the audio recordings in it so manually itself i couldnt understand it so need to find ways to give more clarity ,etc to it

Comment: For future recordings I can use all of your great suggestions, but i need to process this file somehow and hear it and understand the recordings... some how the mic sensitivity or something got messed up while recording so it became less quality than other files...